# Angular to disable ng-repeat checkbox based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox displayed using ng-repeat, now i need to disable some checkbox based on specific value checkbox is checked.

```
checkbox display code

<div class="checkbox">
     <label ng-repeat="specific in specifications">
          <input ng-click="onClick(specific, newObject[specific])" id="specifications_chk" value="{{specific}}" ng-model="newObject[specific]" type="checkbox">
          {{specific}}
     </label>
</div>
```

Here am using ng-click function to disable checkbox.

```
This is my controller code:

$scope.onClick = function(sp, checked){
        if(sp == 'Sofa_Cleaning' && checked === true){
            angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk'))[0].disabled = true;
        }

        if(sp == 'Sofa_Cleaning' && checked === false){
            angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk'))[0].disabled = false;
        }

    };

html view:
```

in controller code am able disable only first value `(IndepthHomeCleaning)`, so how can i disable `Room_Cleaning, Kitchen_Cleaning,` and `Carpet_cleaning` when `Sofa_Cleaning` is `checked`
[image: checkbox view]

Am i stuck with this, Help will be really appreciated

Comment: How about `ng-disabled` ?

Comment: I dont have a idea to return multiple value

Comment: @Nodemon pls check the code now,

Comment: @Nodemon what is wrong in my answer

Comment: You already got sufficient correct answer for this question. Need to see based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change `specifications` array you need a new array and mapping. 
Define new row object for each specification. 
Access specification row and its prop (is active or is disable) from your specification.

http://jsfiddle.net/ms403Ly8/87/

```
function testCtrl($scope, $filter) {
$scope.specifications = ["IndepthHomeCleaning", "Room_Cleaning", "Kitchen_Cleaning", "Carpet_cleaning", "Sofa_Cleaning"];
$scope.specificationRows = [];

$scope.newRow = function(spec) {
    var newSpec = {
        SpecName: spec,
        IsDisabled: false,
        IsClicked: false
    };
    $scope.specificationRows.push(newSpec);
};

$scope.getRowObject = function(sp) {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.specificationRows, {
        SpecName: sp
    })[0];
};

$scope.getRowStatus = function(spec) {
    console.log($filter('filter')($scope.specificationRows, {
        SpecName: spec
    })[0].IsDisabled);
    return $scope.getRowObject(spec).IsDisabled;
};

$scope.onClick = function(sp) {
    $scope.getRowObject(sp).IsClicked = !$scope.getRowObject(sp).IsClicked;
    if (sp == 'Sofa_Cleaning') {
        $scope.getRowObject("Carpet_cleaning").IsDisabled = $scope.getRowObject(sp).IsClicked;
        $scope.getRowObject("Kitchen_Cleaning").IsDisabled = $scope.getRowObject(sp).IsClicked;
        $scope.getRowObject("Room_Cleaning").IsDisabled = $scope.getRowObject(sp).IsClicked;
    }
};
```

}

getRowObject is example. Maybe it's not best practice. You can change this function.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why you are still stick with the jquery.  You are getting
>   by id when you are trying to disable the checkbox.

.

> In html, id should be unique for the current html page. y ou are
>   having duplicated ids and you are getting the first value from the
>   array using [o] when you are trying to disable.

.

> If you strictly want solution from the same method then use the
>   following methodology  Use class name instead of id for the check boxes and use
>   angular element and disable.

The following code should be used where you need to disable. Use appropriate code based on your need.

```
    angular.forEach(document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox1'), function(value, key) {
        angular.element(value)[0].disabled = true;
        debugger
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-disabled`

```js
var angApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

angApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.specifications = [{"text":"IndepthHomeCleaning ", "disabled":false, "checked":false},
                           {"text":"Room_Cleaning", "disabled":false, "checked":false},
                           {"text":"Kitchen_Cleaning", "disabled":false, "checked":false},
                           {"text":"BathroomCleaning", "disabled":false, "checked":false},
                           {"text":"Carpet_cleaning", "disabled":false, "checked":false},
                           {"text":"Sofa_Cleaning", "disabled":false, "checked":false}];
  
  $scope.onClick = function(sp, checked){
    console.log(sp, checked);
        if(sp.text == 'Sofa_Cleaning' && checked){
            $scope.specifications[1].disabled = true;
            $scope.specifications[2].disabled = true;
            $scope.specifications[4].disabled = true;
        }

        if(sp.text == 'Sofa_Cleaning' && !checked){
           $scope.specifications[1].disabled = false;
           $scope.specifications[2].disabled = false;
           $scope.specifications[4].disabled = false;
        }

    };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="checkbox">
     <label ng-repeat="specific in specifications" style="display:block">
          <input ng-disabled="specific.disabled" ng-change="onClick(specific, specific.checked)" id="specifications_chk" value="specific.checked}" ng-model="specific.checked" type="checkbox">
          {{specific.text}}
     </label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating this. Your data object should be simplified to look like this

```
$scope.specifications = [
    {name: 'Sofa_Cleaning', active: false},
    {name: 'Carpet_Cleaning', active: false},
    {name: 'Room_Cleaning', active: false},
    {name: 'Kitchen_Cleaning', active: false},
    {name: 'BathroomCleaning', active: false}
];
```

Template:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    ng-bind="specific.name" 
    ng-model="specific.active"
    ng-disabled="shouldDisable(specific)">
```

in your controller

```
$scope.disableWhenSofaIsChecked = ['Room_Cleaning','Kitchen_Cleaning','Carpet_Cleaning'];
$scope.shouldDisable = function(specific) {
    var disable = $scope.disableWhenSofaIsChecked;
    if(disable.indexOf(specific.name) > -1) {
        for(var obj in $scope.specifications) {
            if(obj.name === 'Sofa_Cleaning') {
                return obj.active;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

So if you're getting specifications data from API, you can just do this:

```
SomeApi
    .get()
    .then(function(results){
        // Assuming it's a promise. End result is the same for a passed-in callback
        // Assuming results is an array of names 
        $scope.specifications = results.map(function(item){
            return {
                name: item,
                active: false
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, problem is am getting this value from api, so i can't add new object

Comment: @Nodemon I'm not sure what you mean. What new object?

Comment: @Nodemon, you can dynamically add object property to the angular object. Api object is different from angular object. When you pass the values to the api, then send appropriate values.

Comment: @user013948 in controller code am getting undefined for **obj.name**

Comment: @Nodemon Show me your array in $scope.specifications

Answer (score 0):

You should not have same id for multiple elements in your code. You need to make you elements ids unique.

HTML :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label ng-repeat="specific in specifications">
      <input id="specifications_chk{{$index}}" ng-click="onClick(specific, newObject[specific])" value="{{specific}}" ng-model="newObject[specific]" type="checkbox" /> {{specific}}
      <br>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.specifications = ['IndepthHomeCleaning',
    'Room_Cleaning',
    'Kitchen_Cleaning',
    'BathroomCleaning',
    'Carpet_cleaning',
    'Sofa_Cleaning'
  ];
  $scope.newObject = {
    'IndepthHomeCleaning': 1,
    'Room_Cleaning': 2,
    'Kitchen_Cleaning': 3,
    'BathroomCleaning': 4,
    'Carpet_cleaning': 5,
    'Sofa_Cleaning': 6
  };
  $scope.onClick = function(sp, checked) {
    if (sp == 'Sofa_Cleaning' && checked === true) {
      angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk1'))[0].disabled = true;
      angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk2'))[0].disabled = true;
      angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk4'))[0].disabled = true;
    }

    if (sp == 'Sofa_Cleaning' && checked === false) {
      angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk1'))[0].disabled = false;
      angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk2'))[0].disabled = false;
      angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk3'))[0].disabled = false;
    }


  };
}
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/f7k3kcwn/

Comment: should strictly avoid the following angular.element(document.getElementById('specifications_chk1')) when ng-disable is available from angular.

Comment: Can you provide some guidelines from angular to support your comment ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'id' attribute which should be unique for each DOM element. So definitely your solution will take single element. So you should try using class attribute and document.getElementbyClass function.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use jquery to for dom manipulation.

Use ng-change instead of ng-click. This will be the appropriate one.

Here I've update a plunkr.

Here for the simple example, I've done like
if the value is check5 then disable all the checkboxes. Otherwise enable the checkboxes.

https://jsfiddle.net/AvGKj/517/

**Note**: I've used little bit old plugin. Please take the logics alone

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="appObj in myAppObjects">
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb1"
        ng-disabled="appObj.disable"
        ng-change="Disable(appObj,myAppObjects)">
        {{appObj.value}}
            </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    {{myAppObjects}}
    <br>list of checked items: {{checkedItems()}}
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.myAppObjects = [
       {id:1,value:'check1'},
       {id:2,value:'check2'},
       {id:3,value:'check3'},
       {id:4,value:'check4'},
       {id:5,value:'check5'}
       ];

      $scope.Disable=function(appObj,list)
      {
        if(appObj.value=="check5")
        {
             for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++)
           {
           if(list[i].value!="check5")
              {
                if(appObj.cb1==true)
                {
                list[i].disable=true;
                }
                else{
                list[i].disable=false;
                }
              }
           }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is with same id on multiple elements. And your code is not event solving the real issue. I guess you disable all other checkBoxes but it has to be selective as per the question described.

Comment: If you think id is the real problem for the checkbox, then I've added same id for the checkboxes. Please check the plnkr https://jsfiddle.net/AvGKj/518/.

He needs the answer like, he needs to disable some specific checkboxes based on one checkbox value. I've added like, to disable all the checkboxes. I hope he has simple logical thinking to change the condition in controller based on the requirement.